# Mongodb replacing dot (.) in key name while inserting document

Tags: ruby, mongodb

MongoDb doesn't support keys with dot. I have a Ruby nested hash that has many keys with dot `(.)` character. Is there a configuration that can be used to specify a character replacement for `.` like an underscore `_` while inserting such data to MongoDb

I'm using MongoDB with Ruby & `mongo` gem.

example hash is like below

```
{
  "key.1" => {
             "second.key" => {
                             "third.key" => "val"
                           }
             }
}
```

Comment: I mean, you can map the hash pretty simply like this assuming `h` is your hash `h.map{|k, v| [k.gsub('.','_'), v]}.to_h`

Comment: this works for first level keys , not for a nested structure in the example I just added

Comment: Are keys always string, or can they be symbols or other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't possible to use keys with `.` in Mongodb, you'll have to modify the input data :

```
hash = {
  'key.1' => {
    'second.key' => {
      'third.key' => 'val.1',
      'fourth.key' => ['val.1', 'val.2']
    }
  }
}
```

## Transforming string keys

This recursive method transforms the keys of a nested Hash :

```
def nested_gsub(object, pattern = '.', replace = '_')
  if object.is_a? Hash
    object.map do |k, v|
      [k.to_s.gsub(pattern, replace), nested_gsub(v, pattern, replace)]
    end.to_h
  else
    object
  end
end
```

`nested_gsub(hash)` returns :

```
{
    "key_1" => {
        "second_key" => {
             "third_key" => "val.1",
            "fourth_key" => [
                "val.1",
                "val.2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

## Transforming keys and values

It's possible to add more cases to the previous method :

```
def nested_gsub(object, pattern = '.', replace = '_')
  case object
  when Hash
    object.map do |k, v|
      [k.to_s.gsub(pattern, replace), nested_gsub(v, pattern, replace)]
    end.to_h
  when Array
    object.map { |v| nested_gsub(v, pattern, replace) }
  when String
    object.gsub(pattern, replace)
  else
    object
  end
end
```

`nested_gsub` will now iterate on string values and arrays :

```
{
    "key_1" => {
        "second_key" => {
             "third_key" => "val_1",
            "fourth_key" => [
                "val_1",
                "val_2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB, there is no configuration to support dot in the key. You need to preprocess the JSON before inserting to MongoDB collection.

One approach is that you can replace the dot with its unicode equivalent U+FF0E before insertion.

Hope this helps.